# click function only once

Tags: jquery, css

Two things. I'm trying to run the code **only once** and not when the `.parent` is clicked again or the `.child` is ever clicked.

Secondly I'm trying to use the `index` value to delay and then a function. Right now it's executing the function every time an image is faded in.

```
$('.parent').one().click(function(event) {
    $(this).removeClass('parent');
    $(this).find('.child img').addClass('sizeimage');
    $(this).find('.hero').addClass('dragimage');
    $(this).find('.child').addClass('dragimage');

    $(this).find('.child').each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide().delay(index * 500).fadeIn(0);
        $(this).addClass('item-' + index);

        setTimeout(reload, index * 500);
    });
});
```

A fiddle of the current setup... with html

http://jsfiddle.net/sw5q9hc0/1/

Comment: Please fix indenting and close tag first

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sw5q9hc0/2/ Try calling the `one` function correctly instead of calling it, then attaching a normal click handler anyway.